# ScalaTest assert and matchers

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

I used ScalaTest in my Scala Play project. But I have a question here, when to use normal `assert(xxx === yyy)` and when to use ScalaTest matchers like `xxx should be yyy`.

Personally I prefer to use assert as it is simple and clean. Also can take advantage of ScalaTest's `TypedCheckTrippleEquals` support, but matchers can't.

For matchers, so far I only found out one thing matchers can do but not assert, which is `Array(1, 2) should equal (Array(1, 2))` succeeds.

Not quite sure which is recommended and are there any other stuff matchers can do more? Otherwise happy to use assert.

Comment: Good question. The documentation [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingEqualityWithMatchers) is really good.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some things that I love from **matchers**:

1) Check numbers in a range

```
sevenDotOh should equal (6.9 +- 0.2)
```

2) Checking length

```
result should have length 3
```

3) Checking for a type

```
result1 shouldBe a [Tiger]
```

4) Checking if an element (or more) belong in a collection

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) should contain oneOf (5, 7, 9)
List(1, 2, 3) should contain (2)
```

5) Various cool tests

```
List(1, 2, 3) shouldBe sorted
```

If you have not read this [documentation](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingEqualityWithMatchers), please do.